# Paragraph Indenting Rules

Tags: style, editing, proofreading

I have a question about dialogue indents. I'm proofreading a piece for my proofreading course and I've come across something that's stumped me.

The first 6 lines of the story are dialogue and they are all unindented. The prose doesn't start until line 7 and that's unindented too.

Now, do I indent them *all* or just the *first* line? And what about the prose on line 7? Do I indent that too or leave it unindented?

I'm using Oxford's [Hart's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hart%27s_Rules) for guidance but it doesn't say much about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Except for the first paragraph of a section, chapter, etc. the first line of each paragraph is indented, whether it is dialogue or prose.

Comment: @Tave this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Is this really part of a proofreader's job? I would have thought that this is an issue for the typesetter to deal with.

Comment: @evilsoup A proofreader or editor handles consistency and adherence to a style guide, so yes, this is an issue for a proofreader.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Hart's Rules](http://www.hartpub.co.uk/hartstyleguide.pdf), *Section 3.2 Paragraphs* has the relevant info:

> New paragraphs following headings should be ranged full left. New paragraphs not
>   following a heading should be indented one tab.

Leave the first line of the story alone, but the dialogue and the paragraphs following should each have a single tab indentation for the first line. The following lines should be *ranged full left* (to use Hart's nomenclature).